# Problems using NSURLSessionUploadTask to post image+string to php server

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I've been trying to figure out how to upload an image to my php-server with NSUrlSessionUploadTask in obj-c, but can't get it to work. I'm trying to send the parameter "longID" and a jpg image with multipart/form-data.

```
//User has confirmed that bilagImage should be used. Now, set up an NSURLSession for posting the image to the php server.


NSString *boundary = @"3kam891boundaryKey28438981";


NSMutableData *bodyData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

//feed the NSMutableData object with a boundary followed by the longID and then yet another boundary
[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat: @"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];              //Add first boundary
[bodyData appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"longID\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];      //Add description of longID
[bodyData appendData:[longID dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];                                                          //Add the longID
[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat: @"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];          //Add boundary



//add the image
[bodyData appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileToUpload\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];   //Add description
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(bilagImage, 0.6);                                                                 //Turn image into NSData
[bodyData appendData:imageData];
[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat: @"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];          //Add boundary


//add the submit parameter
[bodyData appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"submit\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];      //Add description of submit
[bodyData appendData:[@"Upload Image" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];                                                 //Add content of submit
[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat: @"\r\n--%@--", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];        //Add last boundary

NSLog(@"RESULTAT: %@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[bodyData  bytes]]);


// Setup the session
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
sessionConfiguration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{
                                               @"Accept"        : @"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
                                               @"Content-Type"  : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary]
                                               };

// Create the session
// We can use the delegate to track upload progress
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];


NSString *postURLString = @"mywebsite";
NSURL *postURL = [NSURL URLWithString:postURLString];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:postURL];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
request.HTTPBody = bodyData;


NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:bodyData completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    // Process the response
    NSLog(@"response %@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]]);
}];

[uploadTask resume];
```

***The server echoes out "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file."***

PHP-code:

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . $_POST["longID"] . ".jpg";
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Already exists, delete old.";
    unlink($target_file);

}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 3000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
 if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
   && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
 }
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";

}

// if everything is ok, try to upload file
else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what does happen when you run your code? What does it do that you don't want it to do or vice versa?

Comment: I get an error from the php-server. The server accepts file size, file type and recognizes the file as an image. It still gets an error when running the move_uploaded_file-command. When using a regular form action via HTML and web browser everything works fine.

Comment: Added PHP code to the post now.

Comment: Add a print statement to print the value of longID as received on the server, and post a dump of the output of the body text so we can see it (with the JPEG data snipped).